# AutoMapper issue - cannot get ignore property

Tags: c#, automapper

I'm scratching my head trying to get automapper to ignore a poperty, hopefully someone can tell me I'm doing something dumb!

Domain Models

```
public class RamsDocument
{
  // properties...

}

public class Contract
{
  // properties...
  Public IColleciton<RamsDocument> RamsDocuments {get; set;}

}
```

View Models

```
public class RamsList
{
  // properties...

}

public class Contract
{
  // properties...
  Public IList<RamsList> RamsDocuments {get; set;}

}
```

I've tried all combinations to get it to ignore the RamsDocuments properties as you can see they are different types.

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Domain.Models.Contract, ViewModels.Contract>()
                .ReverseMap()
                .ForMember(ignore => igonre.RamsDocuments, opt => opt.Ignore())
                .ForSourceMember(ignore => igonre.RamsDocuments, opt => opt.Ignore());
```

I've got a work around which is to rename the property on the view model to RamsList instead of RamsDocuments which works fine.

If I leave both properties named as RamsDocuments it get the following error when trying to map

> AutoMapperMappingException: Missing type map configuration or
>   unsupported mapping.
>
> Mapping types: RamsDocuments -> RamsList
>   CenelecSiteInspector.Domain.Models.RamsDocuments ->
>   CenelecSiteInspector.WebPresentation.ViewModels.RamsList
>
> Destination path:
>   Contract.Site.Site.Contracts.Contracts.Contracts0[0].RamsDocuments0[0].RamsDocuments0[0].RamsDocuments0[0]
>
> Source value:
>   System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.RamsDocuments_B721359E9A40092B947528944166EA0B12FD5C0B9E9FFD19D91C8409CF04133E

Comment: I hope that `ignore => igonre.RamsDocuments` is a typo and not some `igonre` variable captured in the closure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to put the ignore before the reverse map, because you are ignoring the property in one-way.